# What is the most surprising / interesting application of the inverse function theorem you have ever seen?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology, morse-theory

The inverse function theorem states that:

Suppose that $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a  $C^k$-function 
and that there exists  $a \in U$ such that $f'(a): \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is an isomorphism. Then, there exist $\delta > 0$ and an open ball   $B_{\delta} : = B(a, \delta) \subset U$  such that  $f \mid_{B_{\delta}} : B_{\delta} \rightarrow V \ni f(a)$ is a diffeomorphism, with $V$ being an open set.

There are two remarkable applications of this theorem:

1- Existence of matrices $X$ such that $X^ k = Y$ where $Y$ is a 
matrix sufficiently close to the identity;

2- Differentiable perturbation of the identity: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ a convex and open set. If $ \varphi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^k$, with $|\varphi'(x)| \leq \lambda < 1$ for all $x \in U$, then $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $f(x) = x + \varphi(x)$ is a diffeomorphism on $U$ onto its image $f(U)$.

My goal with this question is to broaden the knowledge about the application/importance of this theorem in other contexts in the areas of Analysis, Geometry, Differential Topology, etc...

Comment: This is a subjective question and has no concrete, acceptable answer …

Comment: Dear @k.stm, from my view point your claim no souds good. In fact if someone give new/ interesting  examples  of application of this theorem will be a gain for community, such examples  will be  in fact  concrete answers.

Comment: hint: dig in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-function-theorem